# Observable events

Tags: c#, events, system.reactive

I have this code, original code [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/d459291a-4245-45ba-8888-35e07f7cf5b2/rx-sample-of-qbservable-provider-for-wmi-events-linq-to-wql?forum=rx), and I need modify to insert output string in List of strings.

How I do that?

```
    private static List<string> list_of_proc = new List<string>();

    static void Run<T>(Func<IObservable<T>> f, Action a)
    {
        Action<string> messageTarget = (x) => list_of_proc.Add(x);
        using (f().Subscribe(t => Console.WriteLine(t), p => messageTarget(p)))
        {
            Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
    }
```

My action messageTarget don't compile.

Out errors:

```
1>Program.cs(20,34,20,59): error CS1660: Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'System.IObserver' because it is not a delegate type
1>Program.cs(20,61,20,82): error CS1593: Delegate 'System.Action' does not take 1 arguments
1>Program.cs(20,61,20,82): error CS1660: Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'System.Threading.CancellationToken' because it is not a delegate type
1>Program.cs(20,66,20,82): error CS1594: Delegate 'System.Action' has some invalid arguments
1>Program.cs(20,80,20,81): error CS1503: Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.Exception' to 'string'
```

This code compile fine with no errors:

```
        static void Run<T>(Func<IObservable<T>> f, Action a)
    {
        Action<string> messageTarget = (x) => list_of_proc.Add(x);
        using (f().Subscribe(t => Console.WriteLine(t)/*, p => messageTarget(p)*/))
        {
            Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
    }
```

Subscribe has this form (System.Reactive.Core.dll, v2.2.5.0):

```
public static IDisposable Subscribe(this IObservable source, Action onNext);
```

This correct code:

```
    static void Run<T>(Func<IObservable<T>> f, Action a)
    {
        Action<string> messageTarget = (x) => list_of_proc.Add(x);
        using (f().Subscribe( t => messageTarget(t.ToString())))
        {
            Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
    }
```

Comment: What's the signature of `Subscribe`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `Subscribe` method is an *extension method*. The `this` parameter is implicitly the object on which you invoke the method. That means that you should only pass the `Action` delegate as the one and only parameter.

```
f().Subscribe(() => Console.WriteLine("Hello"))
```

Answer (score 2):

There are numerous `.Subscribe(...)` extension methods of `IObservable<T>`. The compiler will try to find the most suitable overload. In your case it is trying these overloads in this order:

```
IDisposable Subscribe<T>(this IObservable<T> source)
IDisposable Subscribe<T>(this IObservable<T> source, Action<T> onNext, Action onCompleted)
void Subscribe<T>(this IObservable<T> source, Action<T> onNext, CancellationToken token)
IDisposable Subscribe<T>(this IObservable<T> source, Action<T> onNext, Action<Exception> onError)
```

Your call, however, is this:

```
.Subscribe(this IObservable<T> source, Action<T> onNext, Action<string> ???)
```

None match, but is trying to give you helpful hints:

```
Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'System.IObserver<T>' because it is not a delegate type
Delegate 'System.Action' does not take 1 arguments
Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'System.Threading.CancellationToken' because it is not a delegate type
Delegate 'System.Action<string>' has some invalid arguments
```

Each one effectively is trying to match one of the above overloads.

What's not clear from your code is what the actual type of `T` is when you run the code. Calling `Console.WriteLine(t)` for a `t` of type `T` means that you are probably forcing a `t.ToString()` to output the result - which doesn't always produce something meaningful.

Then to follow up the `Action<T>` with an `Action<string>` also doesn't make sense as `string` isn't an `Exception` and there's no overload of `.Subscribe(...)` that would take an explicit `Action<string>`.

What I think you need is something like this:

```
static IObservable<IList<string>> Run<T>(Func<IObservable<T>> f)
{
    return Observable
        .Defer(f)
        .Select(t => t.ToString())
        .ToArray()
        .Select(ss => ss.ToList());
}
```

Or, perhaps, this:

```
static IObservable<IList<string>> Run<T>(Func<IObservable<T>> f, Func<T, string> toString)
{
    return Observable
        .Defer(f)
        .Select(t => toString(t))
        .ToArray()
        .Select(ss => ss.ToList());
}
```

Then you can call this like:

```
Run<int>(() => Observable.Range(0, 3), n => n.ToString())
    .Subscribe(results => /* handle list of results */);
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using the IObserver as the first parameter for the function but you actually giving it a delegate and the compiler is telling you that it isn't a delegate.
It is as simple as that.